# how to handler a route matching in symfony or other router?

Tags: php, routes, symfony-routing

I'm using the Symfony router component. The router tells you if a defined route match with an incoming request and return you an array with the infomartion of that route(in my case I have defined a controller and method). I wanna know which is the best practice to execute that method. Right now I'm doing something like this:

```
<?php  
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

    $routes = new RouteCollection();

    $routes->add('test', new Route(
            '/test/{id}', 
            ['_controller' => 'app\controllers\testController::test'],
            ['id' => '[0-9]+'], 
            [], 
            '', 
            [],
            ['GET']
        )
    );

    $context = new RequestContext();
    $context->fromRequest(Request::createFromGlobals());

    $matcher = new UrlMatcher($routes, $context);

    try {
        $parameters = $matcher->match($context->getPathInfo());
        call_user_func_array($parameters['_controller'], array_slice($parameters, 1, -1));
    } catch (ResourceNotFoundException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

This works but I don't know if this is the correct way to do it.